# How do I mount an encrypted partition from an Arch Linux iso?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rsync, backup

This will probably be several questions in one and I am happy to supply more detail.  I installed Arch Linux over a week ago with a March 2021 iso from a thumb drive.  I installed with three portions, one was an EFI partition, the second was a Linux partition and the third was a Linux LVM partition with encryption.  An `fdisk -l` command yields the following;

```
Device          Start   End        Sectors     Size   Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1  2048    1026047    1024000     500M   EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  1026048 2050047    1024000     500M   Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme01np3  2050048 2000509230 1998359183  952.9G Linux LVM
```

In addition I installed the gnome desktop environment and have been using this system with several reboots for a week.  I decided to use rsync to backup the entire system and used the following command that came directly from the Archwiki.

```
rsync -aAXHv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /run/media/username/backup_drive_name
```

Although the one thing I forgot to do in my command was add swapfile to the `--exclude` command.  Before running the command I found my backup drive with a `lsblk` command and formatted the drive to an ext4 format.  I then backed up my system and it does appear that everything was copied; however, I did receive an error that not all information was copied.  Immediately after the backup I noticed that I no longer had a wifi connection and could not re-establish it.  I decided to reboot to see if that would fix the problem, but found a bigger issue.  My computer would not reboot.  I checked the BIOS to find that it no longer showed a EUFI boot loader.  I am not sure how, but somehow running the rsync command wiped my boot loader.

I have put the thumb-drive with the iso back into the usb slot and have booted from that.  An `fdisk -l` command shows the same information shown above.  I am trying to mount my encrypted partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` to see if the contents are still in tact and maybe find out what happened.  However, I cannot seem to mount the drive.  I have successfully opened the encrypted partition with the command `crypt setup open --type luks /dev/nvme0n1p3 lvm`. Then I created a new directory with the command `mkdir /mnt/system`. Finally I tried to mount the drive with the following command `mount /dev/mapper/lvm /dev/system` but unfortunately I get the following error; `mount /mnt/system: unknown filesystemtype 'LVM2_member'`.  I ran `ls -l /dev/mapper` and received the following results;

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx   root root 10, 236 Apr 10 12:04 control
lrwxrwxrwx   root root       7 Apr 10 12:04 lvm -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx   root root       7 Apr 10 12:04 volgroup0 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx   root root       7 Apr 10 12:04 volgroup0 -> ../dm-1
```

So my first question is, why am I getting this error and how can I fix it to be able to mount the partition and see the contents?  Second question, is there a way to fix this issue, or am I going to have to reinstall everything manually?  I would consider reversing the `rsync` command and trying to port the backup drive back to my computer; however, the `rsync` command appears to have caused this so it could only make things worse, not to mention the backup did show errors, but I am not sure exactly what they were.

Comment: Do you actually have two `volgroup0` symbolic links in `/dev/mapper`?

Comment: Given that `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is a LUKS device (`cryptsetup` succeeded in opening it), not being able to mount `/dev/mapper/lvm` - if it contains the physical volume of a LVM volume group - is expected (it is not a logical volume by itself). Usually, `udev` takes care of activating LVM volume groups after a `cryptsetup open`, letting logical volumes pop up in `/dev/mapper/`. `lsblk` should show them (you should see `nvme01np3`'s TYPE as `part`, `lvm`'s TYPE as `crypt` and `lvm`'s children's TYPE as `lvm`).

Comment: @fra-san yes, when I partitioned the drive prior to installing linux I created the volgroup with `pvcreate volgroup0 /dev/mapper/lvm` Then I created two volumes with the commands `lvcreate -L 30GB volggroup0 -n lv_root` and `lvcreate -l 100%FREE volgroup0 -n lv_home`.

Comment: @fra-san when I run `lsblk` it does show the following under `nvme0n1p3` it shows `lvm` as `crypt` and under that it shows `volgroup0-lv_root` as `lvm` and `volgnoup0-lv_home` as `lvm`.  As you can tell my linux skills, while they are improving, is at present, intermediate at best.  If you can instruct me on how to view the contents of `volgroup0-lv_home` and `volgroup0-lv_root` it would be very appreciated.  Furthermore any advice on how to restore the system and why it crashed would also be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. As you may have found out, you should mount `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root` and `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home`. Telling what to do to fully restore your system is not easy; you should probably mount `volgroup0-lv_root` to `/mnt`, `volgroup0-lv_home` to `/mnt/home, (assuming your `/boot` is not on a separate partition; mount it to `/mnt/boot` otherwise), chroot into `/mnt` (using `arch-chroot`) and repeat the steps you performed during your initial installation to setup your boot loader and initramfs (refer to Arch's installation guide).

Comment: I did try that a few nights ago and was able to verify the contents, reload the grub boot loader and reboot everything.  If you are willing to post your answer as a response and not a comment I will credit you with helping solve this issue.

Comment: Glad to see you managed to sort it out! I don't feel like posting an answer because I could only give some generic advice and still don't have any clue on what may have caused your issue.